# Range of matrix Set builder notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, machine-learning, math-software

I am unable to to understand this. 
$$
\text{Range}(A) = \{v ∈ R^5:  v = Ax \text{ for some }x\}
$$
$$
\text{Range}(A^T) = \{v ∈ R^5: v = A^Tx \text{ for some } x\}**
$$
Can anyone please explain this in simple words.
this is related to matrix in Linear Algebra.
also please explain what is $\Bbb R^5$. I know $\Bbb R$ is for real number what is 5 for is this telling us that it has 5 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $\mathbb{R}^5$ is the space of vectors of length $5$ which can be thought of as "five-dimensional" Euclidean space. $\mathbb{R}^5$ can be written as
$$ \mathbb{R}^5=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d\\
e
\end{bmatrix} :a,b,c,d,e\in \mathbb{R}\right\}.$$
One thing we know from basic linear algebra is  that an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ can be viewed as a function $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ given by $\vec{x}\mapsto A\vec{x}$ for $\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$. In this case, I suppose that $A$ is a $5\times 5$ matrix, so that $A^T$ is also $5\times 5$. According to the definition, the range of a matrix $A$ is the  set of  vectors $\vec{v}$ in the *target* space which are "hit" by  the transformation. So, to say $\vec{v}\in \text{Range}(A)$ means that we can find $\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^5$ such that $A\vec{x}=\vec{v}$. The same applies for $A^T$, since it also represents a matrix transformation.